# C++ map of map of vectors as instance member

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap

I need the following data structure to store some data:

```
std::map<int, std::map<unsigned long, std::vector<unsigned long> > > lifetime ;
```

the above `map` would be an instance member of a class. The question is, do I need to explicitly initialize the inner containers using `new` or a constructor when I first access them? for instance:

```
if (this->lifetime[sm].find(address) == this->lifetime[sm].end()) {
    (this->lifetime[sm])[address] = std::vector<unsigned long>() ;
}
```

I also don't seem to understand the details of how vectors and maps are initialized as instance members and when nested so I would appreciate some explanation of that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessary if you use `operator[]`.  When `operator[]` is used to reference an element that does not yet exist, an entry is automatically created, with the `mapped_type` value-initialized.

Comment: So something like `this->lifetime[sm][address].push_back(current_cycle) ;` without any prior initialization would work ?

Comment: @parsoa try it and see.

Comment: @xaxxon well it seems it doesn't work and the vector needs to be initialized beforehand, could you explain why?

Comment: @Parsoa yes, that works fine.  You don't need to initialize keys in the map and you can push_back into an empty vector.